# Append to QuerySet Items

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

**Item Model** (represents a product, like a MacBook)

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey('Manufacturer', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    introduction = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    is_retired = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**OnHand Model** (represents a serialized MacBook)

```
class OnHand(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    serial = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    asset = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Item, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.serial
```

---

**Index View**
[image]

**Index Function**

```
def index(request):
    items = Item.objects.all()
    context = {
        'items':items,  
    }
    print(items)
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

**Template/Table**

```
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead class="thead-light">
    <tr>
      <th>Item Id</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Manufacturer</th>
      <th>On Hand</th>
      <th>Category Id</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    {% for item in items %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ item.pk }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.manufacturer }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.quanity }}</td>
    </tr>

    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

---

This application is an Inventory Management System which can take in **Items** such as a MacBook Pro or iPhone 6, and **OnHands** which are serialized instances of these Items. In my **Index Function** I am passing the result of an `all()` query to the **Index View** in **context**.

I can query `OnHand.objects.filter(product_id=item.pk)` to get the quanity of each **Item**, however, in my current way of doing things I'm unsure how I can pass that value to the front end while keeping its relationship if that makes sense.

I would like `item.quanity` to essentially represent the quanity of that particular item. What am I looking for? My initial thought would be to append to the QuerySet but I'm not sure how to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#annotate).

```
from django.db.models import Count
items = Item.objects.annotate(
    quantity=Count('onhand_set__id'),
)
```

Depending on your usage, you may need to pass `distinct=True` to `Count`.

Comment: But now `items` represents a count value rather than each Item object with a quanity included, correct?

Comment: No, it does what you want. Take a look at it in a shell. `items.first().__dict__`.

Comment: Nope, I totally misunderstood how `annotate()` works and this could have solved hours of over-complicating it. Thanks for the help, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Glad you've solved it. `annotate()` works per record in the queryset while `aggregate` will a `dict` of aggregations.

Comment: Adjust your answer though to be `onhand` rather than `onhand_set__id` for accuracy. Debugger spits out what your options are anyways for future readers. :)

Comment: Using `onhand` is not correct as it's not the reverse related name. Your model didn't specify one so it's the model name with a suffix of `_set`.

Comment: `Cannot resolve keyword 'onhand_set' into field. Choices are: description, id, introduction, is_retired, manufacturer, manufacturer_id, name, onhand, tags`. Same when using `onhand_set__id`, but `onhand` works perfectly.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects

Comment: While I totally understand the docs say one thing, the other is what is working with the code above and the debugger explicitly tells me that `onhand` is the only option I can use and does exactly what its supposed to whereas `onhand_set__id` throws an error.